# Netrw error: "Illegal PORT command"

Tags: netrw, spell-checking, error

I installed Vim 8.1.1 on Windows 10.

My `_vimrc` in `C:\Users\Maggyero` has the following lines:

```
set spell
set spelllang=en,fr
set spellsuggest=5
```

When I open Vim, I get the following message:

> Alerte : Liste de mots "fr.utf-8.spl" ou "fr.ascii.spl" introuvable

After clicking on "Ok", I type:

```
:set spell
```

and I get the following message:

> Cannot find spell file for "fr" in utf-8
>   Do you want me to try downloading it?

After clicking on "Yes", I get the following message:

> Downloading fr.utf-8.spl...
>   **error** (netrw) Illegal PORT command.^M
>   **warning** (netrw) file <C:\Users\MAGGYERO\AppData\Local\Temp\VIA45B2.spl> not readable
>   Could not find it, trying fr.ascii.spl...
>   **error** (netrw) Illegal PORT command.^M
>   **warning** (netrw) file <C:\Users\MAGGYERO\AppData\Local\Temp\VIA45B2.spl> not readable
>   Sorry, downloading failed
>   Alerte : Liste de mots "fr.utf-8.spl" ou "fr.ascii.spl" introuvable

Comment: Please read the extensive help for netrw. I would suggesting enabling passive mode (See :h netrw-ftp)

Comment: Note that you can also download the files manually in `~/.vim/spell` with `wget http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/fr.utf-8.spl` and `wget http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/fr.utf-8.sug` . More information (in French) can be found [here](https://vim-fr.org/index.php/Correction_orthographique)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I typed `:let g:netrw_ftp_cmd= "ftp -p"` to switch the `ftp` command to *passive mode*, like suggested in the help, before typing `:set spell`. Now the errors are gone but the warnings are still there, so the downloading still fails. Why do the files are not readable? I even tried executing Vim in administrator mode, without luck.

Comment: as suggested on the Vim issue, could be a firewall problem, it looks like netrw is not able to connect to the given server. You might be able to further debug this issue by following the help at `:h netrw-debug`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: It is not a Windows firewall issue as even when deactivated the downloading fails.

Comment: there might be a firewall between your system and the target system!

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I solved the issue (see below). Thanks for you help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `netrw` invokes `wget` or `fetch` (via `cmd`, not `powershell` which aliases `wget` for the built-in `Invoke-WebRequest` command) for retrieving the spell file:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (wget ^"http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/fr.utf-8.spl^" -q -O ^"C:\Users\MAGGYERO\AppData\Local\Temp\VIA77E3.spl^")
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
```

and the suggestion file:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (wget ^"http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/fr.utf-8.sug^" -q -O ^"C:\Users\MAGGYERO\AppData\Local\Temp\VIA126E.sug^")
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
```

If `wget` or `fetch` is not in the PATH environment variable (which was my case), `netrw` invokes `ftp`.

In *active mode* (the default), `ftp` opens a T.C.P. control connection to the server port 21 and accepts a T.C.P. data connection opened by the server to a client port between 1024 and 65635—so if the *client* has a firewall or a NAT gateway it must be correctly set up.

In *passive mode*, `ftp` opens a T.C.P. control connection to the server port 21 and opens a T.C.P. data connection to a server port between 1024 and 65635—so if the *server* has a firewall or a NAT gateway it must be correctly set up.

As we are behind a NAT gateway (and maybe a firewall) at the office, it might be the reason why `ftp` failed. Switching to passive mode (`:let g:netrw_ftp_cmd= "ftp -p"`) removed the errors but kept the warnings so the downloading is still failing, for a reason that I ignore (maybe because the server has a firewall or a NAT gateway that is not correctly set up, or simply because the server does not allow passive mode).

**So simply installing GNU Wget from Sourceforge and adding it to the PATH environment variable solved the issue: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm**